# Android create custom language and set it on runtime

Tags: android, string, locale

I wan't to use a custom language (like pirate language on minecraft) on my app that the user can select through the settings menu. Normally I would put the strings.xml file into a values-en or so folder. Then I would load it at runtime using this code:

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
    // Change locale settings in the app.
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = new Locale("xy");
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

If I was to create a language in a values-xy folder and then load it using the code and choosing the language xy it does not load it. Is something like that even possible? Creating a custom languag using a non existant language code and use that? Id did not work using the code above.

Answer (score 0):

> It's not possible what are you looking for !!!

**Why ?**

If you put something in i.e `values-en` folder then android will decide run-time according to  what language has selected by OS user .

This is how it made , its an android prototype you cant change it !!